# Вывод меню рубрик в вордпресс

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Есть такая верстка

```
<ul class="pages_list">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="link_1">Отделочные работы.</span><span class="count_pages">45</span></a> </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active"><span class="link_1">Строительство мостов.</span><span class="count_pages">56</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="link_1">Строительство жилых зданий.</span><span class="count_pages">23</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="link_1">Строительство обществен&shy;ных сооружений.</span><span class="count_pages">65</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="link_1">Укладка дорожного покрытия.</span><span class="count_pages">12</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="link_1">Начало повседневной работы по формированию.</span><span class="count_pages">56</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Значения ссылок это рубрики. Нужно чтобы значение ссылок были обернуты в тег span с классом .link_1. А в span c классом .count_pages были количество статей в рубрике. И как узнать id рубрики?

Как это сделать в вордпресс?

Comment: так смотрите свою уникальную тему. уникальные php файлы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

                $menu = wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'depth'=>2,
                    'container'=>false,
                    'menu_class'=>'pages_list',
                    'menu'=>'Сайдбар слева'
                ));

                $categories = get_categories( array(
                    'taxonomy'     => 'category',
                    'type'         => 'post',
                    'child_of'     => 0,
                    'parent'       => '',
                    'orderby'      => 'name',
                    'order'        => 'ASC',
                    'hide_empty'   => 1,
                    'hierarchical' => 1,
                    'exclude'      => '',
                    'include'      => '',
                    'number'       => 0,
                    'pad_counts'   => false,
                ));                 

                if( $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('Сайдбар слева') ) {
                    $menu_list = '';
                    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
                        $title = $menu_item->title;
                        $url = $menu_item->url;
                        if( $categories ){
                            foreach( $categories as $cat ){
                                if($cat->name == $title) {
                                    $catId = $cat->term_id;
                                    $catCount = $cat->count;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        $menu_list .= '<li><a href="' . $url . '" data-catid = '.$catId.'><span class="link_1">' . $title . '</span><span class="count_pages">'.$catCount.'</span></a></li>';
                    }
                    echo "<ul class='pages_list'>".$menu_list."</ul>";
                }
            ?>
```